# add the class of the child to the parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I add the class of the child to the parent so

```
<div class="test">
 <div class="16">

 <div>
<div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="test 16">
 <div class="16">

 <div>
<div>
```

I tried

```
$('.test > div').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(' ');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code was almost there. You just needed to select the parent elements (`.test`), returning the `children('div')` classes inside the `addClass(function)`:

```
$('.test').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).children('div').map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(' ');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52bgp3wc/2/)

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this.

```
$('.test > div').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass(this.className);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.test > div').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="16">
    16
    <div>
      <div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="11">
    11
    <div>
      <div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="12">
    12
    <div>
      <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `addClass()`, it could be:

```
$('.test').addClass(function() {    
    return $(this).children().prop('className');
});
```